# given SD and mean find bserved value of the test statistic?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, order-statistics, statistical-mechanics

I had this word problem where I am trying to see whether new version of something is more precise
so I know that the formula for test stat is

$$\sum_{i=1}^9  \frac{(yi-\mu)}{x^2}$$$ 
where 
$$\sum_{i=1}^9  \frac{(yi-100)}{4}$

in this case I plugged in all the values I had and got this
but what confuses me is that how do I get the answer here without knowing yi?